# 'ButtonToolbar' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: reactjs

I have developed one react application in that I have added react bootstrap through command but when I'm using component of button in code then compiler gives error.

I'm looking for solution. Actually when I'm doing import button in terms page at that time compiler gives error. I want to add buttons in terms page.

I have tried by different two way which is as below :

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

and

```js
import ReactBootstrap, { Jumbotron, Button, Col, Grid, Panel, FormGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


const Terms = () => (<div >
  <p > Terms and conditions content here. </p>
  <ButtonToolbar>
    <Button variant="primary" > Primary </Button>
    <Button variant="secondary" > Secondary </Button>
    <Button variant="success" > Success </Button>
    <Button variant="warning" > Warning </Button>
    <Button variant="danger" > Danger </Button>
    <Button variant="info" > Info </Button>
    <Button variant="light" > Light </Button>
    <Button variant="dark" > Dark </Button>
    <Button variant="link" > Link </Button>
  </ButtonToolbar>
</div>
);

export default Terms;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import [`ButtonToolbar`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/button-group/),

```
import {ButtonToolbar} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

**Note:** You should import only whatever you need, as in your code snippet `Jumbotron, Col, Grid, Panel, FormGroup` not needed (unless it is used somewhere and not shown to highlight only issue).

Also I don't think `react-bootstrap` has coponent called `ReactBootstrap` as you imported.

Comment: I got another error after adding that like "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_react___default.a.createContext is not a function".

Comment: Can you post your folder structure and `package.json` file?

Comment: package.json : 

{
  "name": "react-router-4-example",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "16.1.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "react-dom": "16.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}

Comment: You need a latest version of React. Do this - 1) Delete node modules folder, 2) Change `react` & `react-dom` version in `package.json` file , from `16.1.1` -> `^16.8.6`, 3)  Do `npm install`.

Comment: Actually i have downloaded react application demo and i'm adding bootstrap in that.

Comment: When downloading from another source it might not come up witn all the dependencies, you need to install all the dependecies. Do `npm install` or create a fresh project using `npx create-react-app project_name`.

Comment: Okay. I will create now new reactjs app with fresh setup. Then let you know. Thank you for your great support and answers which is really helpful..